# godotenv command not found after setup

Tags: go

On my mac, I installed go, and setup a REPO from github that use godotenv.

I got the package using

`go get github.com/joho/godotenv/cmd/godotenv`

and run a script

`godotenv -f .env bee run -main=./cmd/web/main.go -runmode=local`

This return

`godotenv: command not found`

My PATH is setup

```
MacTests-MacBook-Air:dooh_frontend mactest$ go env PATH

MacTests-MacBook-Air:dooh_frontend mactest$ go env GOPATH
/Users/mactest/go
```

and inside `go/bin` I do see the `godotenv`

What am I missing ?

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` return? That's the important one here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your `.bashrc/.zshrc` file

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

The `go` env variables isn't relevant to the shell env vars.